# Let $f,g : X \to Y$ be continuous and $Y$ contractible. Show that $f \sim g$.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, homotopy-theory

> Let $f,g : X \to Y$ be continuous and $Y$ contractible. Show that $f \sim g$.

I’m trying to understand the solution here, but getting a bit confused. It seems that I’m doing some sort of composition here?

If $Y$ is contractible, then $id_Y \sim c(x)$, where $c(x)$ is the constant map, by $h:Y \times I \to Y, h(x,t) = (1-t)id_Y(x) + tc(x).$

Now if I construct $H : X \times I \to Y, H(x,t) = h(f(x), t)$, then I have $H(x,0)  = id_Y(f(x)) = f$ and $H(x,1) = c(1) = c(x).$

I tried to sketch some sort of diagram how this goes, but couldn’t do so. I’m confused about $H$ and why it’s defined as $h(f(x),t)$. I can see that switching $f$ with $g$ I get that $f \sim c(x) \sim g$, thus $f \sim g$, but the construction is confusing. What is happening here?

Comment: Be careful: you are using $c(x)$ to denote two different constant maps, one with domain $X$, one with domain $Y$. If we write $c: Y \to Y$ for one of those constant maps, then you know that $id_Y \sim c$, and therefore $id_Y \circ f \sim c \circ f$.

Comment: Also, your formula for $h(x,t)$ doesn't make sense: how are you adding elements of $Y$? (Since $Y$ is contractible, there is a homotopy $h$ between $id_Y$ and a constant map, so you don't need a formula.)

Comment: Not sure I follow. How come I don’t need a formula? @JohnPalmieri

Comment: @Wondera How can there possibly be a meaningful formula that applies to an arbitrary contractible space? Your formula $h(x,t) = (1-t)...$ applies to convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, but there are plenty of topological spaces where there is no notion of addition, no notion of scalar multiplication.

Comment: I see, this clears it. We only now that there is a homotopy between, $c$ and $id_Y$ that satisfies the conditions $h(x,0) = id_Y$ and $h(x,1) = c$, but of course we know nothing about $h$ explicitly since it’s from arbitarty space $Y \times I \to Y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $H: Y \times I \to Y$ is the witnessing homotopy of contractibility that obeys $H(y,0)=y$ for all $y \in Y$ and $H(y,1)=c$ for all $y$ and some constant $c \in Y$, (so a homotopy between $1_Y$ and the constant map with value $c$ on $Y$). We cannot assume this $H$ is some convex combination as $Y$ is just a “bare” space, nothing more (no addition or scalar multiplication need exist).

Then $H’: X \times I \to Y$ defined by $H’(x,t) = H(f(x),t)$ is also continuous (as the composition two continuous maps; a simple product map $X \times I \to Y \times I$ and $H$)) and a homotopy between $f$ and the constant map with value $c$ (from $X$ to $Y$ this time, call this map $c_X$). So $$f \sim c_X\tag{1}$$

Using $g$ instead of $f$ we show $$g \sim c_X\tag{2}$$ and then we invoke the fact that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation to conclude $$f \sim g$$ as required.